# FOUC and body unresolved used with nested templates

Tags: polymer, fouc

I have made a web site using Polymer.js and using templates extensively.

The URL endpoint  pages have very little on them and import a template that acts as a Master Page, and on each of these i import other element templates for headers, footers, etc.

This allows very quick page construction, and i love how it works.
Its kind of like a client side CMS

But i cant seem to get rid of FOUC !! The page flashes badly.

Body unresolved is meant to work, but its failing miserable.
Can someone have a look and make a suggestion please.

Here is the root on git hub.
https://github.com/bmadmin/bm-www/tree/master/public/project/hempbuild

Answer (score 7):

Polymer's FOUC prevention uses the `unresolved` attribute, not a class name:
http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html#fouc-prevention

Have you tried this?:

```
<body unresolved>
  <polymer-home></polymer-home>
</body>
```

The other issue I see is that you're using `<body>` inside polymer-home. However, `<body>` can only be a child of `<html>` according to the spec. The browser will discard that `<body class="unresolved">` from your element.